# Why do headless UI tests on Jenkins fail with 401 Unauthorized?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, watir-webdriver, ui-automation

I am testing UI components of an app with **Cucumber** + **Ruby** + **Watir WebDriver** + **Firefox**. The tests fail when run by Jenkins with every request returning a **401 Unauthorized** page but work when run manually.

The CI server has, amongst other things:

- RHEL 6.5 x64
- Java 1.7.0_60
- Jenkins 1.572
- JRuby 1.7.9
- Cucumber 1.3.12
- Watir Webdriver 0.6.8
- Firefox 24.7.0-1.el6_5
- Headless 1.0.2

When I run the Cucumber scenarios as a Jenkins job, the browser returns **401 Unauthorized** every time.

The tests work when I run *exactly* the same `rake` command from `bash` as the same user who runs Jenkins. The tests also work when run from a Windows desktop (not headless).

It appears that the failure occurs early on because when the browser has an HTTP proxy (an implementation of `WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer`) attached to its profile, the proxy callback code is never reached.

Any ideas?

**New information:**

WebDriver launches a Firefox instance with an HTTP server to control it. During startup, the client part creates a session with an HTTP POST of some JSON to `/hub/session` on the server. It is this request that causes the server to return 401 Unauthorized.

Now to figure out why that happens in a Jenkins job but not from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem was an HTTP environment setting. Jenkins is configured to inject `HTTP_PROXY` into the environment of jobs it runs and the Ruby HTTP client was using that proxy when connecting to the Firefox WebDriver.

**Verification**

When I set `HTTP_PROXY` in the shell before executing `rake` I got the **401 Unauthorized** error.

**Solution**

I added

```
NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1
```

to the environment of the Jenkins job and it executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your tests depend on a particular Firefox profile in order to work properly - is that the case?

It could be the Firefox instance launched by the Jenkins job is not loading the correct profile.

This doc indicates a fresh profile will be created by Watir WebDriver on every run:

http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/

According to that same doc you can specify the profile to load with:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => 'foo'
```

I'll bet that feature uses the Firefox "-P " command line option under the covers; more info on that is available here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Starting_Firefox_or_Thunderbird_with_a_specified_profile

Comment: Thanks for your response Bill, but Firefox profile is not the problem. In the full configuration I explicitly create a profile with the proxy server I want. In the minimal configuration I use the new profile created by Watir WebDriver.

Also, exactly the same configuration works from the command line that fails as a Jenkins job.